# Indy TCP Hole Punching, 10061 Connection refused

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm developing an P2P application which need enable a [TCP Hole Punching](http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/).

For the *Rendezvous* Server I'm using a simple application (running in a public IP) with a `TIdTCPServer` with SSL Enabled, this Application maintains the clients connections and returns the public endpoints (AContext.Binding.PeerIP and AContext.Binding.PeerPort) of the connected clients.

The Client (`TIdTCPClient`) connections to the server have the property  ReuseSocket set to `rsTrue`.

This is how the clients are connected to the *Rendezvous* Server.

```
  TCPClientMain.ConnectTimeout := 500;
  TCPClientMain.Host := RendezvousServerIP;
  TCPClientMain.Port := RendezvousServerPort;
  TCPClientMain.UseNagle := false;
  TCPClientMain.ReuseSocket := rsTrue;

  OpenSSLHandlerMain.UseNagle := false;
  OpenSSLHandlerMain.ReuseSocket := rsTrue;

  TCPClientMain.IOHandler := OpenSSLHandlerMain;
  TCPClientMain.Connect();
```

The issue happens when I try to create a new connection directly to the public end point of the Client **A** from **B**.

## TCP Hole Punching code

```
var
  LTCPClient : TIdTCPClient;
  LOpenSSLHandle : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin

  //Init the SSL for the  new connection
  LOpenSSLHandle :=  TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  LOpenSSLHandle.SSLOptions.Method := TIdSSLVersion.sslvTLSv1_2;
  LOpenSSLHandle.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];
  LOpenSSLHandle.UseNagle := False;

  LTCPClient := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
  LTCPClient.ConnectTimeout := 5000;
  //Set the data of the public end point of the Client A
  LTCPClient.Host := ARemoteIPAddress; //This is the public ip of the Client A
  LTCPClient.Port := ARemotePort; //This is the port of the public endpoint of the client A
  LTCPClient.ReuseSocket := rsTrue;
  LTCPClient.IOHandler := LOpenSSLHandle;

  LTCPClient.Connect(); //This raises a EIdSocketError exception
```

I'm getting Socket Error # 10061 Connection refused.

So, the question is how I can establish the new connection to the public endpoint of the Client without raise that exception?

Comment: It is not enough to just enable `ReuseSocket=rsTrue`.  If you read the linked article more carefully, the section on TCP hole punching clearly explains that your clients need BOTH a listening socket and an outbound connect socket bound on the same local port that is also being used to talk with the rendezvous server. The code you have shown is not opening a listening socket on the local rendezvous port, and is not binding the outbound P2P socket port to the local rendezvous port. Thus, your use of `ReuseSocket` on the P2P socket is useless.  Read the article again.

Comment: Thanks very much @RemyLebeau for you response,  I updated the question adding the code  used by the clients to connect to the rendezvous server.  About this `... your clients need BOTH a listening socket and an outbound connect socket bound on the same local port` Is not the `TCPClientMain` acting as listening socket?

Comment: No, `TCPClientMain` is NOT a listening socket. A listening socket has had the BSD `listen()` function called on it. `TIdTCPClient` uses the BSD `connect()` function instead. When hole punching in TCP, each client needs at least **4 sockets** - 1 connected to the rendezvous server, 1 listening locally (`TIdTCPServer` or `TIdSimpleServer`), and at least 2 trying to connect to the other client's public/private endpoints...

Comment: ... All 4 sockets must be bound to the same local port, which means setting `ReuseSocket=rsTrue` on all 4 sockets. Then, after `TCPClientMain` is connected to the rendezvous server, you can use `TCPClientMain.Socket.Binding.Port` (not `TCPClientMain.Port`) to specify the local port of the other sockets (in the `TIdTCPClient.BoundPort`, `TIdTCPServer.DefaultPort`, and `TIdSimpleServer.BoundPort` properties).

Comment: Again, **read the article more carefully**, these requirements are explained *in detail*. You just have to map the details to Indy equivalents. You are still missing vital steps in that regard. And I strongly suggest you work this out without using SSL at first.  Once you have figured it out and verified it works, then reintroduce SSL. Just make sure you don't set `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.PassThrough=False` until after you validate the correct clients are connected to either other, as there are endpoint validations you should perform after connections are established when hole punching...

Comment: And when you do use SSL, keep in mind that one of the client SSLIOHandlers will have to be set to `SSLMode=sslmClient` and the other set to `SSLMode=sslmServer`, otherwise the SSL handshake will not work.

Comment: Thanks very much @RemyLebeau for all your time and advices,.  Now I have  1). A connection (`TIdTcpClient`, `ReuseSocket=rsTrue`) to the rendezvous  server. 2) a  TCP Server (`TIdTcpServer`, `ReuseSocket=rsTrue`) running  in the same port of the TCPClientMain.Socket.Binding.Port property. 3) A connection (`TIdTcpClient`, `ReuseSocket=rsTrue`,  `BoundPort = TCPClientMain.Socket.Binding.Port`) to the public end point of the peer.

Comment: However I can't figure out how setup the 4 connection (`TIdTcpClient`) to the peer private endpoint.  What values I must use in the Host and Port properties? Because is not the private endpoint the local (LAN) IP Address and port of the peer?

Comment: yes, it IS the peer's private LAN endpoint. **Just like the article says it is**. And yes, it will probably fail to connect (though it might succeed, which is why you have to validate the endpoints on successful connects), but that is not the point. It facilitates the punching process because of the packets it generates.

Comment: Thanks very much. for all your help, Now the exception is gone. Still exists some issues (If I can't resolve these I will post  anew question), but now I'm feel that I'm in the right track. If you want please post a answer with your comments to accept it.

Comment: I have this problem and not solve by doing all explanation above. did you solve your problem . If Solved, can help me. I receive "Socket Error # 10061 Connection refused. "